# OpenDKIM and canonicalization of quotes

Tags: dkim, opendkim

In the long-running battle against a considerable percentage of the DKIM failures for the signatures generated on my servers, I've noted an interesting occurence. Today I've got this DKIM failure report:

```
User-Agent: OpenDKIM-Filter/2.10.3
Version: 0.1
...
Delivery-Result: other
Feedback-Type: auth-failure
Auth-Failure: signature (signature verification failed)
DKIM-Failure: signature
...
DKIM-Canonicalized-Header: (base64 string)
DKIM-Canonicalized-Body: (another base64 string)
```

I've noted that `DKIM-Canonicalized-Header` contained in turn this:

```
cc: Alice A <alice.a@mydomain.com>,
        Bob B-B <b-b@mydomain.com>,
        "'Charlie C'" <charlie@theirdomain.com>
```

and the actual header `cc` was reported as:

```
cc: Alice A <alice.a@mydomain.com>,
        Bob B-B <b-b@mydomain.com>,
        "'Charlie C'"
        <charlie@theirdomain.com>
```

Luckily enough, I've been able to exactly discover what caused the failure. My signing server retained the temporary file /tmp/dkim.* which says the same header was canonicalized a bit differently:

```
cc: Alice A <alice.a@mydomain.com>,
        Bob B-B <b-b@mydomain.com>,
        'Charlie C' <charlie@theirdomain.com>
```

Now the fun part. My signing server runs a very similar build (opendkim-2.10.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) to the verifying remote server and I've been unable to cause it to repeat this buggy behavior, that is to cause canonicalization `"'something'"`. So how could a remote server arrive at such canonicalization? **How could the real header (which I don't have archived on my servers), be such a string that it somehow decoded&canonicalized to `"'something'"` at the remote server and to `'something'` on my server?** Or maybe some additional software tends to alter these quotes during MTA processing? Educated guesses are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There are two canonicalization algorithms specified in the [DKIM specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.4.1). The "simple" algorithm doesn't change the header at all, an the "relaxed", besides converting the header field names to lowercase, only affects white space.

Because of this, I find it very unlikely to have something to do with OpenDKIM.

I looked into [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4). Although `'Charlie C' <charlie@theirdomain.com>` seems to be allowed, it is marked as obsolete (following the ABNF: `address-list` -> `address` -> `mailbox` -> `name-addr` -> `display-name` -> `phrase` -> `obs-phrase`). That is probably the reason something changes it into a `quoted-string`. You should try using double quotes (`"Charlie C" <charlie@theirdomain.com>`) instead.

Comment: I'll try to verify whether it's opendkim's bug or other software's. I've confirmed this happens on my infrastructure (outgoing mail is already broken to `"'something'"`). I'll accept your answer in a couple of weeks max.

Comment: In my case it seems that Sendmail 8.14 rewrites `'sth'` to `"'sth'"` before passing it to the DKIM milter. The respective config is `MustQuoteChars` which defaults to `.'`. Apparently, Gmail rewrites too but after the DKIM test.

Comment: @xebeche do you happen to know what you have currently set MustQuoteChars to? = <empty> ?

Comment: @HenkPoley Can't say why or how much I tested it but in 2016 I had changed it from `.'` to `.` and I can't remember I had problems since then.

Comment: Ah, I had someone come by that RFC 5322 (from October 2008) defines that the dot also shouldn't be quoted (e.g. `MustQuoteChars=`). Do you expect mailservers to be compatible with this 'new' standard by now? The dot was probably kept 'manually' configured for a long time not to break mail-address autodetection too much.